# How do I avoid specifying my gem dependencies in both my Gemfile and .gemspec?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm in the process of creating a Gem the requires other Gems to be installed on the user's system.  I'm doing the traditional thing and specifying my dependencies in my `Gemfile` for `bundle install` to recognize.

It looks like the Gem specification file has a way to specific dependencies as well via:

```
Gem::Specification do |s|
  s.add_runtime_dependency...
  s.add_development_dependency...
end
```

How do I avoid specifying my dependencies in *both* places?

Comment: Have you tried to put the code  `Gem::Specification do |s|` etc into the **Gemfile**? Anyway, the project I saw uses both, but **gemspec** for the settings up runtime, and sometimes development dependencies, and **Gemfile** for in-path developent , test, and other grouping dependences.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Gemfile**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
gemspec
```

In your **.gemspec**:

```
Gem::Specification do |s|
  s.add_runtime_dependency('some-gem-for-production', '>= 3.0.0')
  s.add_development_dependency('some-gem-for-development', '>= 2.0.0')
end
```

Now when you run `bundle install` the **Gemfile** tells `bundle` to look in your Gem Specification file for dependencies.